# How could I select a distinct row from the following table

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select the maximum ID from a combination of SentBy and SentTo
I mean I want To Group (SentTo-SentBy) like 1-3 and 3-1 are grouped together.. Similarlt 1-2 and 2-1 should also be grouped together

What will be the query?

**Users:**

```
**ID | Name** 

1 | A 

2 | B

3 | C

4 | D
```

**Chat**

```
ID | Msg | SentBy (Users.ID) | SentTo (Users.ID)

1 | abc | 1 | 2 

2 | def | 1 | 3

3 | ghi | 1 | 4

4 | jkl | 2 | 1

5 | mno| 2 | 1

6 | pqr | 3 | 1

7 | stu | 3 | 1

8 | vwx| 4 | 1

9 | yz | 4 | 1

10| def | 1 | 3

12| jkl | 2 | 1
```

**Required**

```
ID | Msg | SentBy (Users.ID) | SentTo (Users.ID)

3 | ghi | 1 | 4

10| def | 1 | 3

12| jkl | 2 | 1
```

Comment: What you mean group by together?

Comment: I mean 1-3 and 3-1 are considered in one group

You can see in last table I want to fetch the maximum ID for each
1-2 OR 2-1
1-3 OR 3-1
1-4 OR 4-1

Comment: because mno and jkl has sentBy-SentTo 2-1, but mno has ID 5, and jkl has ID 12

Comment: please dont be so fast, why your solution show `(3,ghi)` as result and not `(9, yz)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()`

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/322de/8)**

```
SELECT Chat.*
FROM Chat
JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(`ID`) m_value
      FROM Chat
      GROUP BY LEAST(`SentBy`, `SentTo`) , GREATEST(`SentBy`, `SentTo`)
     ) C
  ON Chat.`ID` = C.m_value
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID | Msg | SentBy | SentTo |
|----|-----|--------|--------|
|  9 |  yz |      4 |      1 |
| 10 | def |      1 |      3 |
| 12 | jkl |      2 |      1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this

```
select max(id) from chat as c1 
inner join chat as c2 on (c1.sent_by = c2.sent_to and c1.sent_to = c2_sent_by) 
group by c1.sent_by, c1.sent_to ;
```

Comment: not sure if this will work, because there are several `(1,2)` and several `(2,1)`

Comment: yes it isn't working.. [Juan's query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643683/how-could-i-select-a-distinct-row-from-the-following-table/34644079#34644079) worked!